# How to check if a menu exists programatically in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, entities

I have a script where I instantiate and fill menus with menu items programmatically.

Whats the best way to check if a menu already exists if I already know it's ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A menu is a config entity, which means you can use standard entity API to load it.

\Drupal\system\Entity\Menu::load() or \Drupal:entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu')->load()